# Scale UIImage to view size

Tags: c#, ios, uiimage, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm completely new to iOS development in Xamarin, and I'm having trouble doing really, really simple things even after searching for a few hours for solutions to this issue in specific and working through a few tutorials over the last few days.

I've started a brand new, single-view project and am trying to make a background out of an UIImage filled with a 1px wide gradient image that will cover the entire screen (image in the UIImage is set to fill).  UIImage doesn't scale on its own when the screen size changes or I rotate the device, and I can't seem to add constraints to the parent view controller in order to automatically attain the screen size.  I would like to do this in the interface builder as opposed to code, so I can see the background as I build my application.  Is this at all possible?

I realize I can use a CAGradient and size it programmatically, but I would like to learn the way to use an image in case I will need to use it for a patterned background in the future as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In ViewWillAppear... Use this

View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage (UIImage.FromFile ("Images/bg.png"));

Comment: I appreciate the response!  This is an easy way to get a background image for a view, but it doesn't seem to work for a UIViewController (BackgroundColor isn't a property for that class).  I can set the background of a UIView or of a UIImage, but my main issue is getting that view to stretch across the entire screen, regardless of screen size.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make your UIView dynamic (meaning the .Frame property gets modified), you do need to code some of your controls (UI elements).

What you can do, is change the .Frame property of your UIView when you rotate the screen (override method DidRotate), to the .Frame of the encompassing UIView.

```
public partial class someKindOfViewController: UIViewController
{
    private UIView view;

    public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);

        UpdateGUI ();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear ();

        view = new UIView ();

        this.View.AddSubView (view);
    }

    public override void DidRotate (UIInterfaceOrientation fromInterfaceOrientation)
    {
        base.DidRotate (fromInterfaceOrientation);

        UpdateGUI ();
    }

    public void UpdateGUI ()
    {
        view.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, this.View.Frame.Width, this.View.Frame.Height);
    }
}
```

Remember that you have to add other controls to the private UIView, and not the UIView managed by the UIViewController.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Love and regards,
Björn